# How to set the height of a textview on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, height, uitextview

How would I set the height of a textview in code?

I created the textView in storyboard, created a property for it in the .h file and have wired the textView to the property in storyboard.

I can set the text for example as `textView.text = @"some text";`
Now I want to control its height.

However while textView has many text properties, it does not seem to have a height property.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this seemingly straightforward task?

Answer (score 0):

Without constraints:

```
CGRect frame = textView.frame;
frame.size.height = 100;
textView.frame = frame;
```

With constraints:

```
textViewConstraintHeight = 100;
```

To add a constraint:

[image: To add a constraint]

Comment: In the without constraints case I am trying 10, 200,10000 and it not having any effect.  Is there anything I have to adjust in storyboard? It is staying the same size as in the size inspector

Comment: If it's staying the same, it means you have autolayout and constraints. Add a constraint for height in your storyboard.